# JavaScript Url Catcher Like Twitter (Regexp)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I searched but couldnt find something like this regexp. This regexp has to catch every url like "http://domain.com/blabla", "domain.com/blabla", "domain.com", "www.domain.com" ... As the same as Twitter. But it shouldn't catch a special domain. "togl.me", "user.togl.me"... Main domain with subdomains shouldn't be catched.

I'm sorry for my English. Thanks,

Comment: What's special about `togl.me`? It cannot be special, just because you're unfamiliar with it... Just take one of the many RegExps from SO, and strip out the unwanted TLDs (top level domains).

Comment: I don't understand from regex but I found this: `/(^|\s)((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/gi` this does what I want but I have to modify that this shouldn't catch "togl.me"

Comment: What exactely do you want? All domains except for `togl.me` **and** no subdomain (except for `www`)?

Comment: Just all domain except for togl.me

Comment: All domains? So, including subdomains (=contradicting your original post)? What's the purpose of this filter?

Comment: `/(^|\s)((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/gi` this my regex. Can you modify this? This shouldn't catch "togl.me" urls. This is the right question I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pattern matches your criteria:

```
/(^|\s)((https?:\/\/)?(?!([\w-]+\.)*?togl\.me(\/|\s|$))[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/gi
```

It's based on the pattern you provided. `togl.me` is excluded using a negated look-ahead:

```
(?!([\w-]+\.)*?togl\.me(\/|\s|$))           "not followed by the (xxx.)*togl.me"
```

Comment: Yes this solved my problem.. I checked at all and it's working. Thanks a lot Rob.